# ZPL Manually Install a font

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to manually install a font with ZPL.  I have a TTF file and I believe I have the command.  The issue is when I try to print with that font nothing gets printed.

I am able to upload the font to the printer with the following command

```
~DYE:COMIC.TTF,A,T,63040,,AAEAAA.......
```

Note I am truncating the data section, but I also believe this is where my issue is coming from.

After that command completes I can validate that the font is there by running

```
^XA^WDE:*.*^XZ
```

I see the COMIC.TTF font installed, but when I print a label with

```
^XA^FO50,50^A@N,50,50,E:COMIC.TTF^FDSAMPLE^FS ^XZ
```

Nothing is displayed.  I believe the issue has to do with the font not being uploaded correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333380/634911 for the big hint on how to do this.  Instead of using the ~DY command to upload the font I ended up using the ~DU command.  I believe they will do the same thing, but I managed to get it to work with the ~DU command.

The big issue that I was having was the encoding of the TTF font file.  using the template from the mentioned stackover answer I wrote a quick demo program that encodes a TTF file saves it to the DRAM and is then able to use that file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Font
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dirPath = @"<path to directory> i.e. C:\user\";
            var fontName = "comic.ttf";
            var filePath = $@"{dirPath}{fontName}";
            
            
            var data= BitConverter.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)).Replace("-", "");

            var fileSize = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath).Length;

            var zpl =
                $@"^XA^CI~DUR:{fontName.ToUpper()},{fileSize},{data}^FO100,0^A@N,100,50,R:{fontName.ToUpper()}^FDTESTSTRING^FS^XZ";
            
            Console.WriteLine(zpl);
        }
    }
}
```